# Extracting intervals out of an unevenly spaced time series

Tags: clustering, point-process, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am having a list of unevenly spaced data points - just occurrences, no values - and want to split them into intervals grouping occurrences, which are close together like so:

[image]

Currently I am utilizing a fairly simple approach and iterate over the ordered list of time stamps evaluating the distance to the next time stamp and place a *cut* at this position, if the distance is greater than a more or less randomly chosen constant. But it may happen, that there are just a few time stamps within a greater period of time, which could be treated as individuals or might get added to a prior or following group (like demonstrated in the image). Additionally occurences in the middle of two differently sized groups should be added to the bigger one in the best case, I guess, but I am currently not weighting anything as my simple algorithm only knows the past, but not the future items.

The data represents single interactions of a user session and I want to estimate the count and duration of those sessions within a certain interval like a month or week without knowing, when actual breaks appear. I tried to manually optimize the splitting threshold to minimize isolated values without unrealistically stretching the intervals, but the results are not that satisfying. Could there be a kind of clustering method or another approach to this? Maybe for generating a more intelligent threshold. Any hint or literature is appreciated.

Comment: Won't a simple GROUP BY clause in SQL make this series equally spaced?

Comment: The data is stored in a database, but I am unsure why and how grouping the elements via SQL query might help? Could you explain this?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: It might not became clear, what I am intending to do. If there are misleading points or missing information, I will be glad to add them or to edit my question.